# AJAX RoundedCornersExtender not working with multiple forms on a page

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have implemented AJAX RoundedCornersExtender on my site and it works great on pages with only 1 form.  When multiple forms are added the rounded corners end after the first form.  I want it to encompass the entire page (all forms).

When I try to take rounded corners outside the form (so it will surround all form tags) tag it says the rounded corners must be IN a form tag.

Is there a way to either:
1. Put the rounded corners outside the form tag so it will encompass all my forms.
2. Get it to somehow NOT end after the first form closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I moved the panel outside the form tags, the ajax control had to stay inside the form tag but the panel was able to be moved outside the form tags and that works.